# vector inequality

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be vector spaces over real. The function $f:V\rightarrow 
\mathbb{R}$ satisfies :

i. $f(\vec{v})\ge0$ for every $\vec{v}\in V$

ii. $(f(\vec{u}+\vec{v}))^2 +(f(\vec{u}-\vec{v}))^2 = 2(f(\vec{u}))^2 +2(f(\vec{v}))^2$ for every $\vec{u},\vec{v}\in V$

Show that $f(\vec{u}+\vec{v})\le f(\vec{u})+f(\vec{v})$ for every $\vec{u},\vec{v}\in V$

Comment: Have you made any attempt to answer the question yourself?

Comment: Is this yet another contest problem? As I indicated in an earlier post of yours, it is not acceptable to post problems from *current, active* contests. Please clarify, or delete the post and repost when the contest is over.

Comment: Yes this is contest problem. But the contest was not active.. It's 2012 contest